# How to make a flow start the conversation and suggestion chips in Dialogflow CX

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I have been trying to make my own chatbot with Dialogflow CX, I cant see to find enough documentation about this tool.

I am trying to make the bot start the conversation when I join the session but I cant find a way to do it.

Right now my chatbot needs a "hello" or some training word to start the dialog, but I want the chatbot to initiate the conversation.
I think you can do it with "Custom payload" but I cant find an example of how to do it.

Also I know in Dialogflow ES you had a "Suggestion Chip" option where you could put in a button the answer options, but I cant find it on CX. Do I have to code it now?

Right now I am using [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs). Is there an example or other documentation about how to code this bot?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, there is already an answer for how to make the bot initiate the conversation on [Dialogflow CX | How to let the bot initiate the conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905876/dialogflow-cx-how-to-let-the-bot-initiate-the-conversation)

Comment: Oh thanks, and the suggestions chips that where on the ES?

Comment: answered that part just now, sorry i hadn't seen the second part!

Comment: Thanks mate for taking your time! You helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**custom buttons** with hints/suggestions as you outline in your question are only available in Dialogflow CX for integrated services. You can find information about which service is supported on [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration) page. Otherwise, if you are able, you can develop your own integration through their **API**, i'm using the [Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/index.html) one.

If you decide, for example, to activate the Messenger integration to make your bot available via FB Messenger, you can visit the specific page and find, for example, that buttons can be set up [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#button_response_type) way.

There are many other response types, you can browse them in the same page (list, button, description, image, card): for each of them google provides a **sample code** to put in the "Custom Payload" box for the fulfillment. For example a box to *[www.yoursite.org](http://www.yoursite.org)* would work like this:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "button",
        "icon": {
          "type": "chevron_right",
          "color": "#FF9800"
        },
        "text": "Button text",
        "link": "https://yoursite.org",
        "event": {
          "name": "",
          "languageCode": "en",
          "parameters": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

by specifying "**parameters**" or "**event**" you can trigger [Dialogflow events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-custom) to manage the conversation flow.